# calculate any polygons - Area, radius and diagonals sum in C

Tags: math, polygon

I got an assignment to calculate the area, raidus and diagonals sum of an polygon when my input is the
polygons coordinates.
In addition it is written that the polygons are convex.

Regarding the area I  thought of using Shoelace Formula but i saw that it does not work for self-intersecting polygons(or does convex polygons mean that they do not self-intersect).
Does any one know of a formula and its explanation to calculate the area  that will work ?

Regarding the diagonals sum , I dont have an idea how to calculate it, can someone please help out ?

Thanks.

Comment: Convex means all angles are less than 180º. Convex polygons are the simplest and nicest to work with. They can never be self-intersecting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon

Comment: deleted c tag as it is irrelevant

Comment: To get the area of a convex polygon, simply start with one fixed vertex a, then go around the polygon side after side. For each side b,c you calculate the area of the polygon a,b,c. You sum all of these areas to get the polygon area.

Comment: For diagonals, https://www.mathopenref.com/polygondiagonal.html might help. The diagonals are the line segments linking two non-adjacent vertices. Only for regular polygons (say a hexagon), all diagonals have the same length.

Comment: For the area of a triangle, Heron's formula works with just calculating lengths 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: The radius is the distance between the centre and a vertex. For non-regular polygons the radii of different vertices are not all equal. A problem is that there is no standard definition for the centre of a polygon. A simple formula is averaging the vertices.

Comment: Forget about self-intersecting polygons. There are no simple formulas to work with them. Even checking whether a polygon is self-intersecting or not, is a complex problem, far beyond the scope of your homework.